# How do I get a (nx4) matrix rather than a list of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I would like to make an edit that converts my output from a list of arrays to a nx4 matrix - see below:

```
test_labels = []
for i in range(0, number_of_generator_calls):
    test_labels.extend(np.array(test_generator[i][1]))
```

(By the way in the code above I did take out the `np.array` and it made no difference to the output)

```
print(test_labels[0:3])
print(test_labels[-3:])
```

Output:

```
[array([1., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32), array([1., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32), array([1., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)]
[array([0., 0., 0., 1.], dtype=float32), array([0., 0., 0., 1.], dtype=float32), array([0., 0., 0., 1.], dtype=float32)]
```

However, I would like the output to look like this:

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0.]]

[[0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

I want test_labels to come out as an nx4 matrix rather than a list of arrays.

This information about the test generator may be helpful:

```
print(test_generator[0][1].shape)
print(test_generator[0][1])

(1, 4)
[[1. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: try `np.stack(test_labels)`

Comment: `np.array(test_labels)`